# nast.denic.de denies nameserver with code 106

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I've got the following bind9 configuration and seem not to be able to find the source of nast.denic.de's problem on that:

```
@ IN SOA ns.ggkthx.eu. admin.ggkthx.eu. (
        2014070809 ; serial
        8H ; refresh
        2H ; retry
        1W ; expiry
        11h) ; minimum
@    IN    NS    ns.ggkthx.eu.
@    IN    NS    sdns2.ovh.net.
@    IN    MX    10 mail.ggkthx.eu.
mail    IN      A               178.33.157.225
mail    IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
imap    IN      A               178.33.157.225
imap    IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
smtp    IN      A               178.33.157.225
smtp    IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
pop3    IN      A               178.33.157.225
pop3    IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
@       IN      A               178.33.157.225
@       IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
www     IN      A               178.33.157.225
www     IN      AAAA            2001:41d0:8:6587:20::
```

DENIC's nameserver check returns the following errors:

```
106  Received response does not provide expected records directly (resolver, NS, RR)
DEFAULT resolver
ns.ggkthx.eu
ARecord

106  Received response does not provide expected records directly (resolver, NS, RR)
DEFAULT resolver
ns.ggkthx.eu
AaaaRecord
```

The corresponding section (according to error code documentation) "2.1.3 paragraph 3" semms not to even exist.

Any help on finding the problem here would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify `ns.ggkthx.eu` as a nameserver, but there is no `A` or `AAAA` record for `ns.ggkthx.eu`.

Like:

```
ns    IN      A               178.33.157.225
```

Hint: whenever you change your zone, first run `named-checkzone` on it.
It will tell you such problems.

Comment: Is this even required if the nameserver is not in the same zone as the domain itself?

Comment: No. Well I'm unsure what you mean. They need an `A` in their zone of course, but not yours.

Comment: In their own zone they seem to be CNAMEs ;) But named-checkzone just complains that the MX is a CNAME ... You may try it "junboku.de". I forgot to mention the domain in the question

Comment: Thanks. I changed from CNAME to A/AAAA and now it works. I knid of dislike this redudancy (since it's identical to the zone's root), but now it works.

Comment: Right, `NS` cannot point to a `CNAME`